# Ruby on Rails 4 and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm building a project in rails, it's a virtual store for a company. The user should be able to register new products and upload images, so I generated 2 models: "Product" and "Image", Product has_many Images, and a Image belongs_to product, I already ran paperclip to update the Image. "`accepts_nested_attributes_for :images`" is in Product model, so I can save the images from the same product form. The thing is that the images are not being saved. The user should be able to upload 3 images (this is how I allow it "`3.times {@product.images.build}`"). This is my Product Controller:

```
def new
    @product = Product.new
    3.times {@product.images.build}
 end

 def create
     @product = Product.new(params[:product])
     if @product.save
        redirect_to :root
     else
        render :action => 'new'
     end
 end
```

I also tried defining the product_params method like this:

```
private
    def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:title, :info, :description, :price, :images_attributes => [])
    end
```

This is the Request information thrown in the console:

```
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"qRyYjG9pSaFxgCtMddDN3fpbsTeIAagLEz+psd+Z+oHa2AVjXpXYcbxta/Egj2TGrmF3FFNCllkY54dig3aN8g==",
 "product"=>{"title"=>"Title",
 "info"=>"Infor",
 "description"=>"Description",
 "price"=>"9",
 "images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xad3d830 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150820-9643-h6wdta.png>,
 @original_filename="sticker,
375x360.u1.png",
 @content_type="image/png",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[images_attributes][0][photo]\"; filename=\"sticker,
375x360.u1.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">},
 "1"=>{"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xad3d704 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150820-9643-19t1r3v.png>,
 @original_filename="sticker,
375x360.u1.png",
 @content_type="image/png",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[images_attributes][1][photo]\"; filename=\"sticker,
375x360.u1.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">},
 "2"=>{"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xad3d650 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150820-9643-fj3w5g.png>,
 @original_filename="sticker,
375x360.u1.png",
 @content_type="image/png",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[images_attributes][2][photo]\"; filename=\"sticker,
375x360.u1.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}}},
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

If I pass the method `product_params` as a parameter in `@product = Product.new(product_params)`, it save the title, description and price but no the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kept `:images_attributes => []` but it should be `:images_attributes => [:image]`

So, change this:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:title, :info, :description, :price, :images_attributes => [])
```

to:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:title, :info, :description, :price, :images_attributes => [:image])
```

in your `product_params` method.

It should work after that!

For the image validation use this:

```
validates_attachment_presence :image
```

If this validation does not work, then try to use a custom validation like this:

```
  validate :image_present

  def image_present
    if image_file_name.blank?
      errors.add(:image, :image not present")
    end
  end
```

Comment: Oh thank you! Now it is saving, but somehow it's saving nil values in the Image Table

Comment: think you need to add a validation for that.

Comment: I have:
has_attached_file :photo  and validates_attachment_presence :photo

But it says Unpermitted parameter: photo in the console.

Comment: look at my updated answer. add that custom validation instead of your validation, see if that works. let me know.

Comment: wait,. you have? `photo`? change it to `image`? cuz you added: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :images`

Comment: `validates_attachment_presence :photo` should be `validates_attachment_presence :image`

Comment: awesome! Glad I could help :-)

Comment: Hey @GabrielAlejandro, I'm trying to implement multiple image uploading like you are. I did my post controller like you but it's still not working. Could I see your product show page?

Comment: Hi @LoiHuynh, you can check the example at Github, I already uploaded it: https://github.com/csdevs1/image_app